# Have to close and relaunch app for correct location to be shown on map

Tags: java, android, firebase

When retrieving the post's location (Latitude and Longitude) from Firebase, the correct location is retrieved and the marker is placed in the correct spot only after stopping the app and relaunching it. Otherwise, I get the location of some other post...

Anyone can explain to me why that happens? So if I upload a new post and then try to open its location it won't give me back the correct location unless I stop the app and re-enter. If I do everything from one go it gives me the location of another post.

I'm thinking it's a problem I have with my `Adapter` because when I pull up the post from my `ProfileFragment` it gives me back the correct location always.

The way that I am transferring the `postid` from my `PostAdapter.java` class to my `MapsActivityUser.class` is by using Intent, so the correct post can be found in Firebase. How can I fix this issue, and more importantly why is it happening?

**PostAdapter.java**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context mContext;
    public List<Post> mPost;

    public Post post;

    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

    }

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        post = mPost.get(position);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderimg))
                .into(holder.post_image);

 if ("".equals(post.getText_location())) {
            holder.text_location.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.text_location.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.text_location.setText(post.getText_location());

 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView text_location;

 public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

 text_location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_location);

text_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MapsActivityUser.class);
                    intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostid());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
        }
```

**MapsActivityUser.java**

```
public class MapsActivityUser extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    String postid;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        postid = getIntent().getStringExtra("postid");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(postid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                if (post != null) {
                    double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
                    double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivityUser.this, "Event doesn't have location on map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MapsActivityuser.java** updated code with `RecyclerView`

```
public class MapsActivityUser extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    String postid;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private PostAdapter mPostAdapter;
    private List<Post> mPostList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        postid = getIntent().getStringExtra("postid");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mPostList = new ArrayList<>();
        mPostAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, mPostList, postid);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(postid).child("location");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostClick(int position) {
      //
    }
}
```

Comment: in your adapter ```post.getPostid()``` does this method return expected value each time?

Comment: @someuser I just logged it, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. For example, when I access the individual posts by clicking on them in the ```ProfileFragment``` it always pulls up correct location for the post, but when I access the posts from ```HomeFragment``` it doesn't always pull up correct location. For instance, in the ```HomeFragment.java``` the first post's location is correct, and then if I scroll down and open some other post it's location comes back correct, BUT if I scroll back up the second post's location comes back instead of the first's. I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is so wrong. Think about what's happening under the hood. Each time your adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method is called and `post = mPost.get(position);` is executed that is the post is updated at each call. That's why yo're not getting correct post ids.
You probably don't want to set the post to the last and only value updated by the call of `onBindViewHolder()` each time.

I assume what you want is some sort of text_field to display the location of your posts, depending on which is clicked.

**Your position variable is really messed up** and that is not the correct position, instead you should use `getAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: Okay, I am going to try to implement your code. Let you know if it works

Comment: did you understand what the solution is and what your problem was

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm in the process of figuring it out. Give me a sec. Let me process everything you wrote

Comment: In my Activity you said I need to set up a ```RecyclerView```... Why is that?

Comment: that is the fragment/activity  where your ```PostAdapter``` is instantiated

Comment: I just added code with RecyclerView. Can you tell me if I did it correctly?